# Why are C++ Windows Store app header files satisfied with includes in cpp files?

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps

Writing a recent Windows Store app, I was surprised that I could make use of the std::string type without having to include its header. More specifically, the following code compiles without any errors:

StringExample.h:

```
#pragma once

class StringExample
{
public:
    std::string str;
};
```

StringExample.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "StringExample.h"

#include <string>
```

Removing the string include from the .cpp file makes the compiler fail. Shouldn't the string header already be required in the header file?

Comment: Removing *which* include from the .cpp file?

Comment: This also depends on what's in your `pch.h`. Automagic inclusion like this happens quite frequently when using precompiled headers.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry, StackOverflow removed my `<string>` tag in the question text, I've updated it! @Angew Thanks, so it has something to with pre-compiled headers?

Comment: If that is your inclusion order, the `<string>` include shouldn't affect the compilation of "StringExample.h" at all.

Comment: @molbdnilo Okay, rookie mistake. I double-checked the order of the includes in an empty project, and you're right.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing that out to me. No thanks for the downvote ;) I've still learned a lot about C++ includes and compile order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I double-checked the order of the includes in an empty project, and the .cpp file indeed needs to look like this for this to occur:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <string>

#include "StringExample.h"
```

Thus, including `<string>` allows StringExample.h to compile, whereas removing the include makes it fail.